# Расшифровать строку

Tags: php

Добрый вечер. Скачал себе графики для сайта, так вот, там кривая в плоскости задается следующей строкой:

```
[['27-Mar-13',500], ['20-Jun-10', 30.45], ['25-Jul-10', 480.88], ['22-Aug-10', 1000.84],
      ['26-Sep-10', 654.13], ['24-Oct-10', 779.75], ['21-Nov-10', 803], ['21-Nov-10', 903], ['26-Dec-10', 908.56],
      ['23-Jan-10', 501.14], ['20-Feb-10', 1056.51], ['20-Mar-10', 1225.99], ['24-Apr-10', 1386.15]]
```

Данная строка обозначает дату и платёж, как мне составить такую строку при выборки с БД?

Comment: Вы хотите получить результаты из базы и записать их в строку с такой пунктуацией или наоборот, распарсить строку на значения "дата-значение", чтобы значения записать в таблицу базы?

Comment: Записать строку с такой пунктуацией

Comment: А что именно вас озадачило? Дата+Сумма, массив, цикл, implode (при желании). Или вы хотите вот такое прямо из базы получить?

Comment: Я думаю, что это Json как то хитро-выдуманно закодирован

Comment: Расшифруй сначала строку "как мне составить такую строку при выборки с БД"?

Какие данные (и в каком виде) есть на руках; в каком виде они должны быть после преобразования формата? Что-куда собрался писать?

Comment: То есть у меня есть таблица date| prace, её ряды я перебираю, далее преобразую во в такой вид

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишу вслепую, могут быть ошибки:

```
function row_join($date, $price) 
{
    return "['$date', $price]";
}    
$sth = $dbh->prepare('select `date`, `price` from `table`');
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_FUNC, 'row_join');
$string = '['.implode(',', $result).']';
```

Comment: Аха )) Ща @angers777 в ступор впадет )) @klopp, рискуете быть втянутыми в долгую беседу по PDO ;)

Comment: Я вообщем то знаком с ооп, поэтому не впаду. Спите спокойно, товарищ Deonis ;)

Comment: ООП тут и близко не стояло. BTW, это просто пример - не факт, что он лучше или производительней ручной сборки строки, или какого-то другого способа.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так (надеюсь, с базы SELECT умеете делать).

```
echo "[";
//начало тела цикла - перебор значений, выбранных с базы
echo "['" . $row['data'] . "'," . $row['digt'] . "],";
// конец тела цикла
echo "]";
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не очень удачная реализация. Я вообщем то сделать это сумею, но хотелось бы посмотреть как это сделает профессионал, но всё равно спасибо за ответ

Comment: Какая разница как это сделает кто-то другой? Своей головой думать надо учиться, это ж задачка для решения на коленке...